# Customize CancelDlgIcon to show Warning symbol

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6

I need to show warning image instead of information image for CancelDlg in wix. I was able to do that by adding the following code:

```
<String Id="CancelDlgIcon" Overridable="yes" Localizable="yes">WixUI_Ico_Exclam<String>
```

However I have builds for different languages for e.g. fr-fr, ja-jp, en-us, etc.

Only for en-us it is working fine. For other languages the warning icon is not displayed :(

Can anyone please help me and let me know what changes to make so that it works for all languages (es-es, en-us, fr-fr, ja-jp etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should author a `<String/>` element per each localizable string in each `*.wxl` file and provide the appropriate element value (`WixUI_Ico_Exclam` in your case). Moreover, you can have different images for different languages, but that would look strange.

Alternatively (and this option is better for this case, IMHO) you can rely on culture groups, which is basically a fallback mechanism for translations. You can specify several `*.wxl` files to be built into a single MSI package, and in case the phrase is not found in the first file on the line, it will try to find it in the second, and so on. So, for "logically untranslatable" tokens like `WixUI_Ico_Exclam` you can have it once in the `en.wxl`, and provide `en` as a fallback culture to `light.exe`.

See "Specifying Cultures to Build" topic in `WiX.chm` for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this detailed info. I'll try these options :)